# Are Percona Server and MySQL versions tied?

Tags: mysql, percona

I am new to Percona Server. There's one thing that I still don't have clear after reading several pages: Are Percona Server and MySQL tied by version?

In other words, is every version of Percona Server like a fork of the same version of MySQL, and consequently, have in some way the same important changes/differences that MySQL announces on each release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percona has its own set of patches. When Oracle releases a community version of MySQL they port their patches on this version and release a new version of Percona Server.

For example, Percona-Server-5.6.19-67.0 is community MySQL 5.6.19 + Percona patches.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks! :-)